# Creating a tree-like file routing

Tags: javascript, angular

There is such a model:

```
export class Object{
    constructor(
        public object_id: number,
        public date: Date,
        public name: string,
        public comments: string,
        public objects_id: number,
        public object_type: number
    ) { }
}
```

ID `object_id` and `objects_id` are related. Assigning `objects_id` to `object_id`, I can build a tree-like output of files. Which module or component can be proposed to implement this?

Comment: Can you give us more details about your problem?

Comment: @YazanMehrez I have no problem, I just do not know how to implement a tree form on an angular

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for package to build tree, try to install [Angular Tree Component](http://500tech.github.io/angular-tree-component/) and make sure to read the [Documentation](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs)